# How to classify a number of rectangles of different sizes

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, image-processing

I have several rectangles of different sizes. Now I need an algorithm to classify the rectangles according to their size.

The point is that it is not fixed sizes. For example, a rectangle with a width of 30 and height 20, with another rectangle with width 31 and height 19 should be placed in a group. But a rectangle with a width of 40 and height of 30 should be placed in another group.

And determine the number and size of the groups should be done automatically. What algorithm do you recommend me...

In fact, I want to group rectangles based on shape, not area or space them.

Comment: Only you can know what rules should be used for dividing up the groups...

Comment: It _sounds_ like you want to use the area of the rectangles, but really, only you would know what would be an appropiate algorithm

Comment: You have given an example, but that is too little information to determine any algorithm. *Why* would the rectangles be placed in those groups?

Comment: 1st of all this is math and logic not algorithms and C#. Your question is very idiosyncratic.You didn't actually tell us with great precision what the grouping should be. I could try and guess that you're interested in 2 main variables: Width and Height or differently said Ratio and Area (I'm guessing you wouldn't consider a tall tower of height 100 and width 1 similar to a small but tough 10x10 box,right ? So there's the Ratio for you). If that is true, then make a function: Diff(r1,r2,a1,a2)=ABS(r1-r2)+ABS(a1-a2). Then choose a threshold which you believe is the upper limit of "sameness".

Comment: Hamid, do you really not care about the shape? Would you consider a rectangle of size 0.1 * 1000 to be the same as one of size 10 * 10?

Comment: The areas `30 * 20` and `31 * 19` are not identical, only close to each other. Difference `30 * 20 - (30 + 1) * (20 - 1)` seems to be `30 - 20 + 1` or `11`.

Comment: In fact, I want to group rectangles based on shape, not area or space them. @MatthewWatson

Comment: What do you think about using mean, variance and standard deviation to classify them

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted your question as "how do I model the problem of representing sets of rectangles given certain rules".

In set theory, you can define a set by defining a [Characteristic Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) that takes an element and tells you if that element is in the set or not.
That characteristic function can conveniently be modelled by a [Predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) in c#.

So, let's say you have this Rectangle class:

```
public class Rectangle 
{
    public int height {get; private set;} 
    public int width {get; private set;}

    public Rectangle(int height, int width) 
    {
        this.height=height;
        this.width=width;
    }

    public int Area {
        get {return height*width;}
    }
}
```

You can now define your groups as Predicates.
For instance you could define a set of small rectangles like this:

```
Predicate<Rectangle> SmallRectangles = r => r.Area < 100;
```

or you can define a set of narrow and tall rectangles like this:

```
Predicate<Rectangle> NarrowAndTallRectangles = r => r.width/r.height > 1000;
```

This is how it's used:

```
var test = new Rectangle(1,2);
Console.WriteLine("is it small? {0}" ,SmallRectangles(test));
Console.WriteLine("is it narrow and tall? {0}" ,NarrowAndTallRectangles(test));
    // output: 
    // is it small? True
    // is it narrow and tall? False
```

Comment: Actually, the predicate seems to be based on `width + height`, ie. half the perimeter. But I understand that you mean to explain the general case. Very good explanation btw.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not solve my problem. What do you think about using mean, variance and standard deviation to classify them.

Comment: It's an idea as good (and as arbitrary) as any other. The only generally used classification of rectangles that I know of is based on the ratio of the sides. If the ratio is 1 the rectangle can be classified as a square. If one of the sides is 0 length, you have a segment. If both are 0 you have a point. If your rectangles represent tv screen, then you have 4:3 and 16:9 as well.